# Un-encoded ampersands no longer gives an error in W3C validator?

Tags: html, validation

Today I noticed that if my HTML5 page has an ampersand as part of the text, the validator doesn't give an error anymore. It still does if the ampersand is part of a URL.

So, this is valid: Jack & Jill

But this isn't: /index.html?x=0&y=9

This was a local file. I got the same results whether I uploaded or pasted the code into the validator.

What happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that according to the spec, only & immediately followed by a character need to be encoded, but the ones with a white space don't.